# How Top Command works in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select Distinct Top 2 Salary
From Employee
Order By Salary Desc
```

This Query returns Top 2 salary. The order of execution for SQL query(From -> Select -> Order By).

Ideally, it should take salaries in the first two rows and display them but it calculates top salaries. How is the result getting calculated?

How does Top Command work?

Comment: What part of the documentation do you not understand?

Comment: "The order of execution for SQL query(From -> Select -> Order By)" -- nope, SQL is a declarative language. Then engine is free to execute the query in any way it decides to do it, as long as the result is correct according to your specification. Theres's no "order of execution".

Comment: There is no "First two rows" before your ORDER BY hits. There is no inherent order in a table at all. Speaking entirely to the execution path of this query though, the `TOP` is performed last, as designed. The same is true, more or less, for window functions, which also appear in the SELECT clause (as another example that contradicts your incorrect order of operations assumptions).

Comment: maybe this will help explain

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186885/is-there-a-default-select-order

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When you use TOP with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited
> to the first N number of ordered rows. Otherwise, TOP returns the
> first N number of rows in an undefined order.

So since you're ordering by Salary DESC, you're going to get the 2 highest salaries in the table.